# Find the missing Number?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

[image]

This is Tricky Puzzle That Will Totally Blow Your Brain.

Source with answer:

> [enter link description here](https://www.sawaal.com/number-puzzles/find-the-missing-number_8782)

Note:

> if you answer, do it with an explanation.

Comment: it seems like that this puzzle comes from elsewhere. i have provided the source since unattributed work may get downvoted or even closed. happy puzzling ;)

Comment: yeah someone sends me the image and asked for the answer so posted here because I did not have an idea about the solution.

Comment: Maybe make the title less vague?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is:

> 2

Reason:

> Top $\times$ Bottom = Left $\times$ 10 + Right

Comment: This answer is clearly better than hexonimo's.

Comment: @Rubio This comment is clearly contradicting with Rubio's comment

Comment: Don’t listen to that fool Rubio, just listen to the Moderator.

Comment: Who cares about that diamond? @Rubio (JK)

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> $2$

Reasoning

> Multiply the top number in the diamond by the bottom number. The result is $10$ times the left number plus the right number.

Comment: ummm... you sniped my by 1 second  >:( good game +1 ;)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton +1 right back.

Comment: This answer is clearly better than Omega Krypton's.

Comment: @Rubio this answer will in consequence receive a +100 rep bounty (and an upvote) :) .... *looks at top comment made by Rubio under OK's post* .... ermm

Comment: @MrPie I'll offer the bounty coz i want to earn the benefactor badge lol, but it would be only 50 rep so that i dont break my 10k... congrats to hexomino anyway and a +1 from me! (wait sorry i've already upvoted lol)

Answer (score 0):

Ans

> 2

Explanation

> Multiply Vertical numbers.
>  Divide by 10.
>  Quotient on left, remainder on right.